# W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 403

Tags: android, admob

I'm have the error when do this code with my real ID_BLOC And has more than 11 hours to create this ad.

My code 
.....
....
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
....

My Error:
...
...
W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 403
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
.....

But, if i'm using ad request with testing device :

AdRequest adRequest = new  AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("ID_TEST")
.build();

My app show ads successfully.

Could you help me fix this problem ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Loads well with test device. Without it getting http 403 and errorcode 0